# Blackberry OS, how open are they?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am looking forward to developing an app.
This app, was fully 'capable / supported' by the OS on Android, but
not necessarily on iOS

It basically taps on to OS's native phone and message apps to carry out some functions.
(has to be on background, as long as the app is open)
This, however is not possible as you all know, on iOS.

I am trying to forecast the feasilibilty of this app (same functionailty) on Blackberry OS.
I have googled, with keywords like, "how open is blackberry os", "can I build - on blackberry os"

As expected, not much search results.

Please take 1~2 minutes of your time and let me understand where on the graph
Blackberry OS stand on. Thanks.

Close/Sandboxed-------------------------Open/do_whatever_you_want
---------iOS---------------------------------Andriod-----------------------------

Comment: Are you **only** asking about BlackBerry 10, or are you including legacy BlackBerry Java smartphones, too?

Comment: It depends. On some specific points, you are free to do whatever you want. On some others, you are not. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: It's possible to invoke application on message received and send messages (that's for bb10). I'm not quite sure what else you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would categorize both BBOS (older Java based phones) and BB10 (new C++ based phones) as closed.

But, in a lot of cases with BBOS especially, there are provided API functions for close interaction with the native apps, including email and phone applications.  So if the requirements you specify are all you require, then I suspect you can do it in BBOS.

BB10 is a work in progress. AFAIK, the listeners for these applications are not there yet. For example, there is no notification on a phone call.  Moreover, until 10.2 OS, which is just out, there was no way to have a background, always running app (and even now, to get one of these, you need to ask BB to give you the required permissions).  But these APIs are, as I understand it, coming.  And if there is a need, I think BB will provide it (why I think all the APIs are there in BBOS).

So as a previous comment has said, the correct answer is 'it depends'.  On BBOS, you need to check the doc to find out If you can do what you want.  On BB10, I'm betting it is probably not there yet, but could well be in the near future.

The only other thing I would say is, if it is not provided, then you will not be able to hack it in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I suspect newest models of Blackberry run on BB10? or can they run both BBOS BB10?..?

Comment: @taesu - the newest BBs, the Z10, Q10, Q5 and Z30, run BB10 only.